# It does print out, but it doesn't write in csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

I'm trying to save a table on this website > https://www.valuewalk.com/2019/01/top-10-most-obese-countries-oecd-who/

It does print out, but it doesn't save in a CSV. Can someone help out giving some advice?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


#Request webpage content
result = requests.get('https://www.valuewalk.com/2019/01/top-10-most-obese-countries-oecd-who/')

#Save content in var
src = result.content

#soupactivate
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')


#look for table
tbl = soup.findAll('ol')
tbl2 = tbl[1]

#Get text out of table
tbltxt = tbl2.get_text()

#Open CSV
file = open('obesecountries.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(file)

#Put data into csv
for row in tbltxt:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

I found the HTML table I would like to get out of. I removed the HTML tags.
It prints out but it doesn't save/write in CSV.

Comment: `get_text()` returns a string. Why are you looping over it?

Answer (score 2):

`tbltxt` is a string, not a list. You should be looping over the `<li>` elements.

And the argument to `writerow()` should be a list, not a string.

```
for li in tbl2.findAll('li'):
    rowtext = li.get_text()
    write.writerow([rowtext])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
#Open CSV
file = open('obesecountries.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(file)

#look for table
tbl = soup.findAll('ol')

#Put data into csv
for row in tbl:
    # get the text from the second item in the row
    txt = [row[1].get_text()] 

    #Get text out of table
    writer.writerow(txt)
```